# My AC blows warm air

Tags: air-conditioning

I am renting, and my previous AC unit sounded like a diesel generator so the maintenance team replaced it with a new one.  It is the [Garrison Air Conditioner, Through the Wall, 14,000 BTU, 230/208 Volts, Cool Only](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VQ66KJ2).  I called maintenance the other day because it was running for 2 days straight and the temperature in the apartment was sitting around 78 degrees for the room with the AC and .  They instructed me to turn off the energy saver mode and to turn the desired temperature to 62 degrees (the lowest the unit will go).

Cold air (62 degrees) does come out occasionally, but it is generally 75 degrees.  It has been in the high 80's outside the past few days, and I have also noticed at night it does a much better and consistent job of cooling, and I do not think it is a coincidence that when the temperature outside drops, the AC is is cooling better.

Is there something wrong with my AC? The previous place I lived, when I set the AC, it would take a few hours at most to hit the right temperature, but this one takes 8 hours to drop 2 degrees in a 1 bedroom apartment.

Comment: that sounds like the AC is not working as it should  ..... you should really change your title to `My AC blows warm air` .... it describes the problem

Comment: Since the air intake is outside and that is 90 degrees, I considered 75 to be cool in comparison, but yeah, it does blow warm air.  I think it might be the compressor from what I have read, but I am not savvy with this stuff.

Comment: Low on refrigerant I bet

Comment: @Kris even though it is brand new supposedly?  The management can be stingy so I want to know what I am talking about when they come.

Comment: I hope you know that an air conditioner is supposed to cool the air inside your home by continuous recirculating of indoor air . If you have your unit pulling in air from outside you need to switch it over to recirculate.

Comment: Your unit claims it features air exchange option. You would want that off for maximum cooling.

Comment: The maintenance person said it was pulling air from outside.  Did you find a manual that stated the air exchange feature?  I have no clue how to change that.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam  the link you provided has the info under product description

Comment: @Kris I don't see that anywhere on the Amazon page.  I did find the manual thought.  It might be the sensor is being frozen, which would explain why after an hour of warm air it blows cool air for a bit.  https://content.interlinebrands.com/product/document/10138/2477805_Installation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

GARRISON 2498545

The image below from the amazon link. 
[image]
The area in red box is where air from your room is drawn into the unit. It passes over the supercooled coil and exits back into your room through the top vents. Do not obstruct air flow into the unit. Set mode to cool,energy saver off, temperature to lowest 62, fan to high.

And if there is a setting or manual method fir opening a vent to let outside air into the home close it. Amazon page describing this unit photo below. 
[image]
Take note of the feature called air exchange. This would be a feature allowing the option of introducing fresh outside air into your home during the cooling cycle. Obviously you want that off on very warm days.

If all of that still does not give you lots of continuous cool air there us something wrong with the unit and it needs to be serviced by a qualified ac technician